# Dynamic amount of parameters in where clause

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot

At the beginning i need to say that the way I trying to do it might be silly but it's only one that I figured it out.

I have table with car properties, one time I need get date by one parameter
{
  "mark": "Audi"
}

other time i need more specific
{
  "mark": "Audi",
  "model":"A4"
}

So I write method

```
    public List<Object> findVehicleProperty(String propertyType, Vehicle vehicle) {
    String queryParam = "";

    if(vehicle.getMark() != null) queryParam += "mark='"+vehicle.getMark()+"'&";
    if(vehicle.getModel() != null) queryParam += "model='"+vehicle.getModel()+"'&";
    if(vehicle.getEnginePower() != null) queryParam += "engine_power="+vehicle.getEnginePower()+"&";
    if(vehicle.getSeatCount() != null) queryParam += "seat_count="+vehicle.getSeatCount()+"&";
    if(vehicle.getDoorsCount() != null) queryParam += "doors_count="+vehicle.getDoorsCount()+"&";
    if(vehicle.getGearboxCount() != null) queryParam += "gearbox_count="+vehicle.getGearboxCount()+"&";
    if(vehicle.getType() != null) queryParam += "type="+vehicle.getType()+"&";


    //remove last "&" mark
    if (queryParam.length() > 0) {
        queryParam = queryParam.substring(0, queryParam.length() - 1);
    }


    return vehicleRepository.getParameters(queryParam);
}
```

which return WHERE clause from sql "mark=Audi&model=A4, then I tryed to pass this part of sql as parametrer to Repository

```
@Query(value = "select * from Vehicle where ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> getParameters(String query);
```

I console I can see that it interpate kind of well

```
2018-10-29 21:35:57.488 DEBUG 6240 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select * from Vehicle where ?

2018-10-29 21:35:57.494 TRACE 6240 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [mark='Audi'&model='A4']
```

but this request always return empty collection, if I use select * from Vehicle where mark='Audi'&model='A4' directly on DB I get correct results.

Have You any idea why ?

Comment: You are dealing with SQL and not with url query parameters. It should be `mark=Audi AND model=A4`.

Comment: The funny thing is, that he is not getting SQL syntax error ;)

Comment: Most likely it is searching for car mark that is `Audi&model=A4`.

Comment: It's not a case. By only mark='Audi' I still getting nothing

Comment: @tsilakp Nah this does not make any sense neither.

Comment: Are you sure you can do something like that in the SQL `mark='Audi'&model='A4'` What kind of db is it? This is simply invalid SQL, so it should not work by any means.

Comment: @plucins Then show how the data is stored in DB. Is the the column value in JSON?

Comment: @Antoniossss I dont see single quotes present around values in his example or code.

Comment: Its MySql - https://imgur.com/BuV7BnC

Comment: @tsolakp why would you? Its the idea of prepared statements to do such things for you.

Comment: Since when & is a valid substitute of `AND` ??

Comment: @Antoniossss. Will JDBC put single quote inside the string value or just around it?

Comment: IMHO it should throw exception but looks like it escapes the value with ''. And definetly around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use prepared statements to "inject" whole where clause as it will escape your "native string" so you will end up with

```
SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE '123456'
```

or something similar.

For dynamic Criterias (that is your case) use `CriteriaAPI`  so `CriteriaBuilder` will be your friend here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did it using Your suggestion to use Criteria API and its work like I expected

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion would be [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) in SQL terms.

**NOT SURE IF THIS WOULD WORK  in Spring**

And in your case it could work like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Vehicle 
WHERE COALESCE(mark = :mark, true) and 
      COALESCE(model = :model, true)  and   
      COALESCE(engine_power = :engine_power, true) and 
      COALESCE(seat_count = :seat_count, true) and 
      COALESCE(doors_count = :doors_count, true) and 
      COALESCE(gearbox_count = :gearbox_count, true) and 
      COALESCE(type = :type, true) ;
```

This suggests you would put all the possible parameters as an `" and  COALESCE(attribute = :attribute , true)" or " and  COALESCE(attribute= ?1 , true)"`

Comment: [Why not w3schools.com?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280478/6426692)